# How do I read pure raw mic data in Chrome in Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, audio, webrtc, getusermedia

My aim is to capture high-quality music audio in my webpage running over Chrome in Android. 
For this purpose, I have been fiddling with getUserMedia API.

I am passing the following constraint to the get media:

```
constraints = {echoCancellation: {exact: false},
                autoGainControl: {exact: false}};
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: constraints}).then(record_processor);
```

And following is how I process the stream received in the getusermedia callback:

```
function record_processor(stream){
console.log('in record_processor');
context = new AudioContext();
var source  = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
buffer_size = 1024*16;
var processor = context.createScriptProcessor(buffer_size,1,1);
source.connect(processor);
processor.connect(context.destination);
sample_rate = context.sampleRate;
console.log('sample rate: ' + sample_rate);

total_iterations = ((TOTAL_RECORDING_TIME*sample_rate)/(1000*buffer_size));
console.log('total iterations: ' + total_iterations);

counter = 0;
var chunks = [];
processor.onaudioprocess = function (e){
  var buffer = new Float32Array(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0));
  chunks.push(buffer);

  //console.log('buffer: ', buffer);
  console.log(counter);


  counter +=1;
  if(counter > total_iterations){
    console.log('iterations complete');
    context.close();
    //stopStreaming();
    console.log('audiochunks: ', chunks);
    data = mergeBuffers(chunks, chunks.length*buffer_size);

    console.log('data', data);
    wav_view = encodeWAV(data);

    var audioBlob = new Blob([wav_view], {type: 'audio/wav'});
    //forceDownload(audioBlob, 'recording.wav');
    console.log(audioBlob);
    get_song(audioBlob, sample_rate);
  }
};
```

}

The issue is that this gives me preprocessed and not the raw audio data. Apparently, Chrome applies some background noise detection and tries to cancel out any pattern lasting longer than half a second.

Can you guys please ask me in how to ask Chrome to not apply any filtering/preprocessing on the audio and provide me with pure raw data as received by the mic's hardware?

Below are the waveform and spectogram of the mic data I am receiving:

[chrome output's waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyNWR.png) 
[Chrome output's Spectogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy9IO.png)

Comment: Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getSupportedConstraints - `noiseSuppression` seems similar to what you are experiencing.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks. I have tried that earlier but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tested on different devices?

Comment: yes, I have tested it on over 5-6 devices with varying brands and Android OS.

Comment: I'm curious if you've tested recording your audio source with a native android app and seeing the same effects. I've also found this issue about [WebRTC using the Experimental AGC](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=918677&q=component%3AInternals%3EMedia&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) in the Chromium bugs which may be related or not.

Comment: I have tested it on on app and it works flawlessly.

thanks for sharing that bug detail. I will definitely check it out.

Comment: I checked the bug and it doesn't help. the output music is still faded